GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) ReactJS/Nodejs Project in AdminLTE template
I'm a newbie in Nodejs and trying to integrate the AdminLTE dashboard template in my react project.
my project structure
src/
|-- components/
|   |-- admindashboard/
|   |--AdminDashboard.js
|   |--Navbar.js
|   |--Sidebar.js
|   |--Content.js
|   |--Footer.js
|   |--adminpage/
|   |    |--Dashboard.js
|   |    |--Smslog.js
|   |    |--Payment.js
|   |    |--Amortization.js
|   |    |--Usermanagement.js
|   |    |--Usergroup.js
|   |    |--Application.js
|   |--context/
|   |    |--AuthContet.js
|   |--hooks/
|   |    |--useProtectedRoutes

|--Login.js

in my //server.js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_key', // Change this to a random string
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false } // Set secure to true for HTTPS
}));

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'lms' // Change this to your database name
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to database');
});

app.post('/Login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error executing query:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    } else if (results.length === 0) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
    } else {
      // Authentication successful
      // Store user role in session
      req.session.role = results[0].role;
      res.json({ message: 'Login successful', role: results[0].role });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


//login.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = ({ setIsLoggedIn }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/Login', {
        username,
        password
      });
  
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Set session cookie
        document.cookie = `role=${response.data.role}`;
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        navigate(`/${response.data.role.toLowerCase()}dashboard`);
      } else {
        setError('Invalid username or password');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setError('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="card card-outline card-primary">
        <div className="card-header text-center">
          <a href="/Login" className="h1"><b>Welcome</b></a>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="input-group-append">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                  <span className="fas fa-user" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="input-group-append">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                  <span className="fas fa-lock" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {error && <div className="text-danger">{error}</div>}
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-6">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

can you help me guys. the problem is when i run this code, it works fine not until you go to other tab or refresh the browser. i get the error "GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)" any advice will do.
